# File [imagedefinitions.json] does not exist in artifact [testart] - AWS CodePipeline - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-codepipeline

I am working on a pipeline with AWS Code pipeline using Jenkins as a
build provider. Jenkins has a plugin(AWS CodePipeline plugin) to connect/poll
with the pipeline.

Flow of the pipeline:

Source - CodeCommit
Build - Jenkins
Deploy - CloudFormation

Jenkins produces an output artifact(testart which contains imagedefinitions.json) that is uploaded to s3 using
the plugin. For some reason, CloudFormation is able to find the artifact, but not the imagedefinitions.json file.

The error that I get in the deploy stage:

**"File (imagedefinitions.json) does not exist in artifact (testart)"**.

PS: The pipeline has full permissions to access s3.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is the artifact just the zipped `imagedefinitions.json` file? Flat, without any directory structure?

Comment: @MilanCermak it's just the file and not zip, there is no directory structure either. The AWS CodePipeline Plugin that Jenkins uses to upload the artifact says - If the location is a normal file: the file will be uploaded as-is (no compression).

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+CodePipeline+Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An artifact in a CodePipeline is a zipped directory. You refer to the files inside this dir:

```
.
└── JenkinsArtifact
    └── imagedefinitions.json
```

So you just need to put the `imagedefinitions.json` into a directory and have Jenkins zip it.

Comment: One clarification: Many CodePipeline actions expect and create artifacts in the ZIP format, but it's entirely possible to add custom actions or Lambda functions that use a different container format (GZIP) or store arbitrary blobs (e.g. JSON) as artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

The CloudFormation action expects a zip file, so you should configure Jenkins with a directory instead of a file.